# How to install app_echo.so in FreePBX?

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

What is the proper way of installing app_echo module when FreePBX is installed ? I cannot find it in Module admin and manual editing of configuration files when freepbx presented is not recommended, is it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, freepbx web have shortcut for Echo.

It can be founded in "Feature Code". Default is *43 and it is enabled.

app_echo.so by default is on in all major asterisk's version.

Note, freepbx is web,and not have any relation to binary of asterisk. But usualy app_echo.so is present.